# MVC4 - How to call controller method from razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i am new with MVC, can someone please help me and explain how to call controller method from a view.

I have HomeController and inside it I have method ShowFileContent().

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ShowFileContent()
{
    string filepath = Server.MapPath("\\Files\\Columns.txt");    
    try
    {
        var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filepath);

        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            ViewBag.FileContent += line + "\n";

        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        ViewBag.FileContent = "File not found";
    }

    return View();
}
```

Inside view I've tried to call this method with code bellow but it does not work.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ShowFileContent", "Home"))
{
    <input type="submit" value="Show File" style='width:300px'/>        
}
<h2>@Html.Raw(ViewBag.FileContent.Replace("\n", "</br>"))</h2>
```

I get error: The view 'ShowFileContent' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations.

What i am doing wrong and whats the best way to call methods from razor view ?

Comment: is your controller called "HomeController"?

Comment: try specifying the FormMethod i.e. `Html.BeginForm("ShowFileContent", "Home", new { }, FormMethod.Post, new { }))`

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47517862/error-in-mvc-passing-data-from-view-to-controller-or-its-master-was-not-found/52877539

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds to me like its breaking on your

```
 return View();
```

If you dont tell it where to go it thinks the view is called the same as your action.

so instead try

```
return View("Name of your view");
```

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thank you very much !! I was trying to figure this out for last 2h.

Answer (score 7):

You can use inbuilt Action method to call action from View.

```
@Html.Action("actionName", "ControllerName")
```