# error in MVC passing data from view to controller : or its master was not found or no view engine supports

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need help.

I'm trying to push the data to controller -> MembersController .

my code :

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("updateMember","Members", FormMethod.Post))
{
 .
 .
 .
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="submit" />
}
```

**Controller** MembersController

```
   [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult updateMember(Member m)
    {
        // Add member
        bamc.SetMember(m)
        return ...
    }
```

**ERROR**
 The view 'updateMember' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lw0um.png)

Comment: do you have *updateMember.cshtml* named view in the particular Views folder (Views/Members) ?

Comment: no i don't have ? Name of the View is RequestMembers.cshtml

Comment: What exactly are you returning (or intend to return) from your action?

Comment: the mistake was in return. thanks for the hint

Comment: Duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22209425/mvc4-how-to-call-controller-method-from-razor-view

Answer (score 1):

The name of your view should be the same as the method or you can pass a name in the method parameter. e.g return View("updateMember") also if you needs pass some object to your view, you should pass it with parameter of method View("updateMember", someObject). Other overloads you can see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.View%28System.String,System.Object%29)

Comment: Not necessarily.. [`return View()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.View%28System.String,System.Object%29) has overloads that accept View names with the object you want to pass to it.. Your explanation makes it seem as though that is the **only** way.

Comment: It has 7 overloads. Should I explain all of them? I have explained how he can fix his mistake.  You can see other overloads in intellisense of visual studio

Comment: Why should **you** have to explain all of them?  They are already explained on the page that I have provided a link for.  Maybe you should update your answer to include that link and some possible written examples which would best help the OP.  Start by reading [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding.

Comment: @GTown-Coder, I have edited the answer. Thank you and happy coding too

Answer (score 0):

The `return …` that you have at the end is the key.  You should've put what you actually had when you had the error, and if you had a question about what it should be, asked it directly or added something like:

```
return View(); // is this right?  what should this be?
```

We needed to see what your code actually had in order to know why it was erroring.  The full update code is also lacking, since it's not clear if `bamc` is another `Members` viewmodel/model or the database context model. I'm making the assumption your `return` statement is as I've stated above, and that `bamc` is the retrieved `Member` object from the database.

When you do `return View()`, MVC assumes the View you want to show is named the same as your method you are calling, so it looks for that name with various extensions (i.e. .cshtml, .ascx, etc.) in the folder under `/Views/{your controller name}`.

It is not required to actually have a View in that folder with the name of your function, however, if you, instead, redirect to/explicitly specify an existing View that DOES reside there and accepts the model/viewmodel you want to pass to it (assuming the View you call accepts a model).

If you are updating a member's information, you might want to redirect to a page that is listing that information on a display page after the update, so the user can see that the information got updated.  So you'd probably redirect to a "MemberDetails.cshtml" View with a routine that went like:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult updateMember(Member m)
{
    Model1 db = new Model1();
    Member bamc = db.Members.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MemberId == m.MemberId);

    // Update member        
    bamc.Name = m.Name;
    bamc.Address = m.Address;
    // … etc. ...

    db.Entry(bamc).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();

    return View("MemberDetails", m);
}
```

Where "MemberDetails" is a View that is located in a folder under the path `/Views/Members` and accepts a `Member` model (has `@model YourSite.Models.Member` at the top of the page).

If you did not want to pass a model and just intended to redirect to a list of Members, perhaps a View in that same path called "MembersList", it might be:

```
return View("MembersList");
```

It all depends on what you want to do (which also wasn't provided in the question).